# PCA on ESP32 - libraries and recommendations?

Tags: esp32, data

it would seem that this would be a commonly sought-after topic, however I cannot find straightforward libraries for this and it's taking too long, so please allow me the question:

**Is there a good library for Arduino/ESP32 to run principal component analysis (PCA) on a 3D matrix?** Any links etc welcome, [EigenArduino](https://github.com/vancegroup/EigenArduino) is the 'only' library I could find but it's not exactly straight forward (no example code etc). I want to extract the first component of some data sized `3x3000`.

Thanks

Comment: this looks like example code https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html#title1